# How to find the error line in a multi file document

Tags: errors, winedt

How can I find the error line in a multi file document? Usually WinEdt5 goes to the error line when double clicking on an error (at least with single files). When I include files, this is not working anymore and it jumps to the last line of the main file. I also don't know where to look up the error line by hand as it gives me e.g. an error on line 906, which is somewhere in the included files but I have no idea where. Is the an output file where I can look up the line numbers and find the error? (I'm using PDFLatex). Jumping to the error line would of course be even better.

Comment: Updating your WinEdt may fix this problem, current version number is `8`. What's more, the log file shows which file is processing by TeX engine, reading the log file could also help you find errors.

Comment: The log-file tells you which file has just been opened. Also did you try to setup your main file as "main file" in winedt? At least in an actual winedt (winedt 5 is old!) it is then able to jump to include files.

Comment: I don't think this will help you - but other editors handle external files correctly: TeXnicCenter for Windows and TeXStudio on Windows and Linux.
Or maybe as others have said - update to the current version of your editor.

Comment: Well I guess for updating one needs a new license...

Comment: TeX Live provides all of its tex engines with a command line option that gives error messages in the format <file>:<line>:<error>. I'm sure MiKTeX has this also. With that option, the .log file will show you which file the error was in.

Answer (score 2):

[To get this off the unanswered list]

You are using a really obsolete version of WinEdt...

Every version >=6 is able to locate the error in the right file.

It suffices that you set your main document as a "main file" through the command "Set Main File" available in the "Project" menu or in the Tree interface toolbar.